# Please burninate the "untagged" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged) does not mean anything. Any question should at least belong to one tag, so this is useless. It should be burninated.

Note:  I had retagged the questions that had [untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged) to their corresponding tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand the purpose of [untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

It is a system tag that is used for questions that only have one tag, so that when that tag is destroyed they aren't "broken".  We can't do anything about it without breaking the system.

Comment: Sorry for that, but should I retag the questions back to [tag:untagged]?

Comment: @EmersonHsieh Nope. **Nothing belongs** in untagged, it's just a unfortunate byproduct of how the system is written. *shrug*

Comment: So(just to be sure) the system uses this tag when the only tag on  a question gets deleted?

Comment: @EmersonHsieh Correct.

Comment: @Emerson Usually you see these tags from imported questions from other SEs,so we need to tag them to fit.

Comment: @LordofTime that tag wiki will disappear in about 24 hours, it's somewhat useless. :(